# Do you say "I'm afraid yes" instead of "I'm afraid so"?

Tags: ellipsis

### Can I say "I’m afraid yes" to mean "I'm afraid so"?

In these conversations, you are B. Read the information in brackets and then answer with I think so, I hope not etc.

(You’re at a party. You have to leave early.)
A: Do you have to leave already?

My answer
B: I’m afraid yes.

The correct answer in the book
B: I’m afraid so.

Source English Grammar in Use Intermediate Unit 51.4.6

Comment: To regretfully answer positively, 'I'm afraid **so**', to answer negatively, 'I'm afraid **not**'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

*So* cannot be replaced by *yes* in this kind of construction. I think it is best treated as an idiom, because there is some substitution possible, but not freely.

So

> I think so.

> I believe so.

> I suspect so.

> I'm afraid so.

> I imagine so.

> I fear so.

But not

> *I'm certain so.

> *I know so.

> *I'm delighted so.

> *I doubt so.

(The first two are occasionally used as an emphatic reply to a question in this form, eg "Do you really think so?" "I **know** so!", but they are not used otherwise.)

But I don't think the *so* can be substituted, and certainly not Yes.

In your originial scenario, you might hear *I'm afraid, yes*. But this has a different intonation pattern from *I'm afraid so* (which is why I've written it with a comma).

Comment: "No" is very judgemental. According to you, anyone can say anything they want, as you don't believe in any rules of grammar.

Comment: _No_ is not in the least judgmental. It is a statement of (what I believe to be) fact, that native English speakers do not and would not, use that expression. Of course, I may be factually wrong. Descriptivists are used to prescriptivists making the ludicrous claim that they "don't believe in any rules of grammar".